# QClipboard's setMimeData fails to copy value in Android

Tags: android, qt, qml, clipboard, mime

I have a qml application that runs both on iOS and Android and it seems like QClipboard's setMimeData fails to copy a value with "com.myapp.filesystem.myclient.wifi" as a key (an empty value is copied).

iOS: When I copy something with "uri-list" as a key, it is copied. When I copy something with "com.myapp.filesystem.myclient.wifi" as a key, it is copied.

Android: When I copy something with "uri-list" as a key, it is copied. When I copy something with "com.myapp.filesystem.myclient.wifi" as a key, then the value of this key is empty (when copying in to the application's clipboard).

p.s.: p->clipboard is QApplication::clipboard()

```
void FileSystemGlobals::copyUris(const FileSystemID &fromFileSystemID, const QStringList &uris) {
  auto data = mimeData(fromFileSystemID, uris).toMap();
  
  auto mime = new QMimeData();
  
  for (auto i = data.constBegin(); i != data.constEnd(); i++) {
    QByteArray bArray = i.value().toByteArray();
    QString key = i.key();
    mime->setData(key, bArray);
    qDebug() << i.key() << i.value().toByteArray();
  }
  
  qDebug() << mime->data("com.myapp.filesystem.myclient.wifi");
  
  p->clipboard->setMimeData(mime);
  
  const QMimeData *mime1 = p->clipboard->mimeData();
  qDebug() << "mime1" << mime1->data("com.myapp.filesystem.myclient.wifi");
  qDebug() << "mime1" << mime1->data("text/plain");
  qDebug() << "mime1" << mime1->data("uri-list");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any solutions for the above problem so I am presenting a work around.
I passed the uri list as a text with a custom mime-type. So the above code became:

```
void FileSystemGlobals::copyUris(const FileSystemID &fromFileSystemID, const QStringList &uris) {
    
#ifdef Q_OS_ANDROID
      if (fileSystem(fromFileSystemID)->ID() == FileSystem::NOT_LOCAL_FILESYSTEM) {
        QStringList uriStringList;
        //  function that joins all uris to one QString
        QString text = joinMimeString(uris);
        text.prepend(s_androidNonLocalFsMimeType);
        p->clipboard->setText(text);
        return;
      }
    #endif
    
      auto data = mimeData(fromFileSystemID, uris).toMap();
      auto mime = new QMimeData();
      for (auto i = data.constBegin(); i != data.constEnd(); i++) {
        mime->setData(i.key(), i.value().toByteArray());
      }
    
      p->clipboard->setMimeData(mime);
    
    }
```

}

s_androidNonLocalFsMimeType is a unique string that is prepended in order to be sure that the uris are from the specific non-local-filesystem.

Inside my paste method the unique string is removed and then the string of uris is splitted to a QStringList.

And that's all!